# 'she must NOT have made it' vs. 'she mustn't have made it' vs. 'she must have not made it'

Tags: modal-verbs, infinitives, negation, semantics

In this passage there is a slight pause after 'must' and a stress on 'not':

'I saw Isabella she had a blank expression on her face. I'm not sure what happened with the knife she was carrying it looked like she was still holding on to it, and I looked down and I saw my wife on the floor blood everywhere all over the bathroom. I was talking to the dispatcher and the dispatcher told me, 'Make sure you get her breathing again. Get her airways open.' I don't know CPR so... But at that time I looked at my wife's eyes and I knew that **she must not have made it**. I just couldn't, couldn't believe that, that it had happened like that. Isabella was in a rage like I've never seen before.'

(from an interrogation of Ryan Hoy, Youtube video 'When An Insane Teen Killer Makes Detectives Snap')

**Would there have been any difference in meaning if he had said, '...she mustn't have made it' or 'she must have not made it' instead?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is speaking 'off the cuff' and using rather unconventional syntax while describing a painful incident - obviously he means 'not have made it' as a euphemism for 'be dead'. Personally I would find **She must have not made it** a bit more natural here.

*Must* is of course being used in the sense 'probably was' rather than that of obligation to do something, but the order of words doesn't really affect the meaning.

Comment: Would 'She must have not made it' be pronounced as 'She must've not made it'?

And wouldn't 'she mustn't have made it' in our context mean 'she was supposed to die but she didn't' or 'she had to die but she didn't'?

Comment: Yes, except in very careful speech _must have_ is pronounced _must've_ and _must not, mustn't_. As I said, _must_ here does NOT have the 'obligation' meaning.

Comment: But then there are sentences like 'To be admitted, the student must not have done any prior work in this subject.'

Comment: There are indeed, and in those cases _must_ does have the 'obligation' meaning.

Comment: Would the above sentence be equivalent to

 'To be admitted, the student must have not done any prior work in this subject.', 
or

 'To be admitted, the student must haven't done any prior work in this subject.', or

 'To be admitted, the student mustn't have done any prior work in this subject.' ?

Comment: _Must haven't done_ is not valid English. A formal statement of rules like that would not include contractions, so _mustn't have done_ is unlikely, and the first version isn't very natural. (I suggested that "She must have not made it" would be natural because the phrase _not make it_ is an idiom for _fail_ or _die_.)

Comment: How many Brits realise these points and can put these into words, or at least follow them subconsciously? 0.1%? 0.01%? Because I could not find the answers even in A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language. What made you first start reading books written by intelligent people?

Comment: I said in my answer that it was _my personal opinion_ that that version was more natural, not a rule. No native speaker would say _must haven't_.